# How to sum the array elements by reduce method js

Tags: javascript

why my cod is not working i mean can i even sum with reduce method?

```
function sum() {
    let numbers = [] ;
    let result ;
    while(true) {
        let input = prompt("Enter a number or press 'S' to submit") ;
        if(input === "s" || input === null) {
            break;
        }
        numbers.push(Number(numbers)) ;
    }
    **let submaition = numbers.reduce(myfun); 
    function myfun(a , b) {
        result = parseInt(a) + parseInt (b) ;
        return result ;
    }**
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. When asking a question it is better to show what research you have done into your problem and post detail of errors you are getting. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reduce function is o.k. The problem is that you are not pushing the correct value to the Numbers array. Instead of:

```
numbers.push(Number(numbers)) ;
```

Use this:

```
numbers.push(Number(input)) ;
```

I hope this helps you out.

Answer (score 1):

Yes

```js
const euros = [29.76, 41.85, 46.5];

const sum = euros.reduce((total, amount) => total + amount); 

console.log(sum) // 118.11
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass initial value to the reduce function also there is an error in `numbers.push(Number(numbers)) ;` it should be `numbers.push(Number(input)) ;` here is a working snippet:

```js
function sum() {
  let numbers = [];
  let result;
  while (true) {
    let input = prompt("Enter a number or press 'S' to submit");
    if (input === "s" || input === null) {
      break;
    } else {
      numbers.push(Number(input));
    }
  }

  let submaition = numbers.reduce(myfun, 0);
  function myfun(a, b) {
    return parseInt(a)+ parseInt(b);
  }
  console.log(submaition);
}

sum();
```

Answer (score 1):

There are few issues in the implementation,

- It should be `numbers.push(Number(input))` rather than `numbers.push(Number(numbers))`
- And if a string is entered then the result will be `NaN`

I have addressed these issues in the below code.

```js
function sum() {
    let numbers = [] ;
    let result ;
    while(true) {
        let input = prompt("Enter a number or press 'S' to submit") ;
        if(input === "s" || input === null) {
            break;
        }
        if(isNaN(Number(input))) input = 0;
        numbers.push(Number(input));
    }
    console.log(numbers);
    let submaition = numbers.reduce(myfun, 0); 
    function myfun(a , b) {
        result = a + b ;
        return result;
    }

    return submaition
}

console.log(sum())
```

Hope this helps.