# how to sum consecutive numbers of array until remaining only one

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sum, addition

I want to sum the numbers of array in javascript, and create others rows of this sum, until it get only one
I want to generate new rows as result of the previous sum.
it is only for training algorithms

```
EX: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] 
     [3,7,11,15]
      [10,26]
       [36]
```

```
function retsum(x) {
    for(let i = 0; i < x.length - 1; i++) {
        console.log(x[i] + x[i + 1] )
    }
}
retsum([2,3,5,6,10,20])
```

this is my code. I dont know how to generate other loop or other solution, to keep doing this sum, until remaining only one number
if you can help me, thanks

Comment: why not sum directly?

Comment: So loop by two and push to a new array and repeat

Comment: whats the point of even doing this?

Comment: Rather an abstract exercise than anything of real practical use, I suppose? You should go look into _recursion_.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning _why_ you're doing this. It makes sense only if this is a programming exercise/homework.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sum the array elements by reduce method js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62454728/how-to-sum-the-array-elements-by-reduce-method-js)

Comment: What should happen if there was an odd number of items in the initial array, such as `[1, 2, 3]`?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur: will knowing the reason imply different code ??

Comment: Is computing in-place allowed or not ? What when the number of elements is odd ?

Comment: @DavidThomas I mention this up in [my response below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75185581/1762224).

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl: like the commenter to your own answer, I prefer to ask the OP what their intent/requirement is in this situation; especially as this edge-case is so predictable I'm not sure it even qualifies as an "edge" case.

Comment: @DavidThomas I never said, "edge case". I just said that it was something to consider. Also, Stack Overflow is a tool for people to discover solutions to questions they may also have. Adding more information is better for future searches on the site.

Comment: Your function `retsum` does not correspond to the first example and the line `retsum([2,3,5,6,10,20])` is mysterious, to say the least. Sorry but your question is of a low quality.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl: no, you didn't; but what point are you trying to make? My previous response to you was to try and explain why *I* raised the question for OP, nothing I said was a discussion of your answer. I'm aware of what the site is, and its use-case; I also strongly advocate for trying to teach where possible (check out some of my own answers as an example).

Comment: A [recursive solution](https://ramdajs.com/repl/#?const%20repeatedSums%20%3D%20%28xs%29%20%3D%3E%20%5B%0A%20%20xs%2C%20...%28xs%20.%20length%20%3C%202%20%3F%20%5B%5D%20%3A%20repeatedSums%20%28Array%20.from%20%28%0A%20%20%20%20%7Blength%3A%20Math%20.ceil%20%28xs%20.length%20%2F%202%29%7D%2C%20%0A%20%20%20%20%28_%2C%20i%29%20%3D%3E%20xs%5B2%20%2A%20i%5D%20%2B%20%28xs%20%5B2%20%2A%20i%20%2B%201%5D%20%7C%7C%200%29%0A%20%20%29%29%29%0A%5D%0A%0ArepeatedSums%20%28%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%2C%204%2C%205%2C%206%2C%207%2C%208%2C%209%2C%2010%5D%29) is fairly simple.

Answer (score 1):

You can use while loop check if array size is above 1

```js
function retsum(x) {
    const result = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < x.length - 1; i++) {
        console.log(x[i] + x[i + 1] )
        result.push(x[i] + x[i + 1] )
    }

    return result
}

let arr = [2, 3, 5, 6, 10, 20];

while (arr.length > 1) { 
    arr = retsum(arr)
    console.log(arr)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a recursive approach and return a single value at the end of recursion.

```js
function sum(numbers) {
    console.log(...numbers);
    if (numbers.length === 1) return numbers[0];
    const result = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i += 2) {
        result.push(numbers[i] + (numbers[i + 1] || 0));
    }
    return sum(result);
}

console.log(sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sum pairs of numbers in an array, you have to decide if you are doing it left-to-right, or right-to-left. Depending on the route you go, all the intermittent arrays between the initial input and the final result will vary. Take note of the output of each snippet below.

Recursion would be the easiest way to tackle this. It all comes down to how you increment/decrement your for-loop and push/unshift the sub-array.

### Left-to-right (increment)

```js
const print = (arr) => console.log(...arr.map(JSON.stringify));

const recursiveSums = (numbers, result = [numbers]) => {
  if (numbers == null || numbers.length === 0) throw new Error('array length less than 1');
  if (numbers.length === 1) return result;
  const subResult = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i += 2) {
    subResult.push(numbers[i] + (numbers[i+1] ?? 0));
  };
  result.push(subResult);
  return recursiveSums(subResult, result);
};

print(recursiveSums([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])); // even
print(recursiveSums([5, 3, 8, 4, 1]));          // odd

try { recursiveSums([]) }                       // error!
catch (e) { console.log(e.message); }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

#### Output

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] [3,7,11,15] [10,26] [36]
[5,3,8,4,1] [8,12,1] [20,1] [21]
array length less than 1
```

### Right-to-left (decrement)

```js
const print = (arr) => console.log(...arr.map(JSON.stringify));

const recursiveSums = (numbers, result = [numbers]) => {
  if (numbers == null || numbers.length === 0) throw new Error('array length less than 1');
  if (numbers.length === 1) return result;
  const subResult = [];
  for (let i = numbers.length - 1; i >= 0; i -= 2) {
    subResult.unshift((numbers[i-1] ?? 0) + numbers[i]);
  };
  result.push(subResult);
  return recursiveSums(subResult, result);
};

print(recursiveSums([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])); // even
print(recursiveSums([5, 3, 8, 4, 1]));          // odd

try { recursiveSums([]) }                       // error!
catch (e) { console.log(e.message); }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

#### Output

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] [3,7,11,15] [10,26] [36]
[5,3,8,4,1] [5,11,5] [5,16] [21]
array length less than 1
```

**Note:** You really don't have to decrement in the right-to-left example. You could just subtract the index from the length of the array and `push` rather than `unshift`.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i += 2) {
  subResult.push((numbers[numbers.length - i - 2] ?? 0) + numbers[numbers.length - i - 1]);
};
```

Comment: As long as the size is a power of 2, the order does not matter. In fact the OP never specified what to do in the odd cases.

Comment: @YvesDaoust well, it is something to consider. It is present for completeness.

Comment: Rather than filling holes "in case", I prefer to ask the OP his intent (and warn him about the incompleteness of his question).

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with using `reduce`. It covers empty or odd-numbered input arrays.

```js
function addPairs(nums,left_to_right)
{
  nums=nums.length>0?nums:[0]
  const evenNumberOfItems=[...(nums.length%2===0?nums:left_to_right?[...nums,0]:[0,...nums])]
  const pairs=evenNumberOfItems.reduce((previous,current,index,array)=>{
    if(index%2===0)
      previous.push([current,array[index+1]])
    return previous
  },[])
  const addedPairs=pairs.reduce((previous,current)=>{    
    previous.push(current[0]+current[1])
    return previous
  },[]);
  console.log(addedPairs)
  return addedPairs.length===1?addedPairs[0]:addPairs(addedPairs);
}
console.log(addPairs([]))
console.log(addPairs([2,3,5,6,10,20,13],true))
console.log(addPairs([2,3,5,6,10,20,13],false))
```